# How can we fetch user friendly messages out of the error thrown in catch block of Amplify - Error Handling on Amplify.Swift iOS

Tags: aws-amplify

```
 func userLogin(userId: String, password: String?,completion: @escaping (Bool?, String?, Error?) -> Void) async {
            do {
                let signInResult = try await Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: userId, password: password)
                switch signInResult.nextStep {
                case .confirmSignInWithSMSMFACode(let deliveryDetails, let info):
                    print("SMS code send to \(deliveryDetails.destination)")
                    print("Additional info \(String(describing: info))")

                    // Prompt the user to enter the SMSMFA code they received
                    // Then invoke `confirmSignIn` api with the code
                
                case .confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge(let info):
                    print("Custom challenge, additional info \(String(describing: info))")
                    
                    // Prompt the user to enter custom challenge answer
                    // Then invoke `confirmSignIn` api with the answer
                
                case .confirmSignInWithNewPassword(let info):
                    print("New password additional info \(String(describing: info))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.showResetPasswordViewForFirstLogin,
                                                        object: nil, userInfo: [:])
                    }
                    
                    // Prompt the user to enter a new password
                    // Then invoke `confirmSignIn` api with new password
                
                case .resetPassword(let info):
                    print("Reset password additional info \(String(describing: info))")
                    
                    // User needs to reset their password.
                    // Invoke `resetPassword` api to start the reset password
                    // flow, and once reset password flow completes, invoke
                    // `signIn` api to trigger signin flow again.
                
                case .confirmSignUp(let info):
                    print("Confirm signup additional info \(String(describing: info))")
                    
                    // User was not confirmed during the signup process.
                    // Invoke `confirmSignUp` api to confirm the user if
                    // they have the confirmation code. If they do not have the
                    // confirmation code, invoke `resendSignUpCode` to send the
                    // code again.
                    // After the user is confirmed, invoke the `signIn` api again.
                case .done:} } catch let error as AuthError{
                print ("Sign in failed \(error)")
                completion(true, error.errorDescription, error)
            } catch {
                print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
}
```

Im getting error in the second catch instead of the first one how can i get error of type Auth Error

I want to fetch the error.errordescription from Auth error but since its throwing NSerror type im unable to fetch value out of it